# Jquery Spinner Load Value/Refresh Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using the jquery spinner within an MVC application. I implement its HTML and JS within the cshtml file.

```
<p>
    <label for="spinner">Select a value:</label>
    <input id="spinner" name="value">
</p>
<script>
     var spinner = $("#spinner").spinner();
     spinner.spinner("value", 10);
</script>
```

When the spinner loads and is initiated for the first time I want it to take the value of 10, however when the user has interacted with it and changed the value on subsequent refreshes of the page I want user selected number to be maintained, not it returned back to 10.

As I am new to JS then the only way I can think of achiving this is reading/writing to a database which holds the number, 10 as default until it is over written?

I thought I would ask in case there is a slicker solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to keep a user-set value persistent during full page refreshes, you'll need to store it somewhere, for example in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this.

**Situation:** The user interacts with the spinner and refresh the page (this is happening only in user PC, no submit button has been pressed).

**Solutions:** For this situation you can store your spinner value in **Cookies.** (Cookie keep data on client side and they are made *available* on server side)

Or you can make an async call to server that update the value in **Session** (Session keep data on server side and is unique for each user) or, as you said, in **Database** (Database keep data on server side and you have to make sure that the value is retrieved for the right user).

**Note:** I don't write the code for this because I want you to research about this (I know **you can do it**).

Knowing the difference between Cookies, Session and Database choose what fits best for you.

Comment: A cookie doesn't *"keep data on the server side"*. It makes data *available* on the server side, but cookies are persisted in the user's web browser

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker You have hawk eyes :D. This was my thought when I wrote it. Thank you for helping me be more clear on my words.